# Only last row of json list is populating in Pandas Dataframe - Draftkings

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I am attempting to load data from Draftkings Sportsbook into a Pandas Dataframe.
Unfortunately, in my attempts, I am only able to get the last row of a list to populate in the Dataframe. Are there any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import json_normalize
from functools import reduce


def parse_data(jsonData):
    results_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for alpha in jsonData['eventGroup']['offerCategories']:
    
        alpha_df = json_normalize(alpha).drop('offerSubcategoryDescriptors',axis=1)
     
        for theta in alpha['offerSubcategoryDescriptors']:
            theta_df = json_normalize(theta)
            theta_df.columns = [str(col) + '_offerssub' for col in theta_df.columns]
   
    temp_df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right, left_index=True, right_index=True), [alpha_df,theta_df])
    results_df = results_df.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
    return results_df

jsonData_dk_nba = requests.get('https://gaming-us-in.draftkings.com//sites/US-IN-SB/api/v2/eventgroup/103/full?includePromotions=true&format=json').json()

nba = parse_data(jsonData_dk_nba)
nbapanda=pd.DataFrame(nba)
```

Comment: there's this: https://jaebradley.github.io/draftkings_client/api/

Answer (score 0):

This is an extraordinarily deeply nested response. Not sure if you can limit it or if you really want all of it, but using `flatten_json` works well to pull all the data in. You'll just have to import the module.

If you want particular offer category (there seems to be 8), you could create dataframes for each of those. Below is the entire set in one dataframe.

```
from flatten_json import flatten
dic_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in jsonData_dk_nba['eventGroup']['offerCategories'])
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)
dft = df.T
```

df outputs this (over 16000 columns and 8 rows):

```
       offerCategoryId          name  ...  offerSubcategoryDescriptors.4.offerSubcategory.offers.0.0.outcomes.30.participant offerSubcategoryDescriptors.4.offerSubcategory.offers.0.0.outcomes.30.hidden
    0               62    Game Lines  ...                                                                                NaN                                                                          NaN
    1               66  Series Lines  ...                                                                                NaN                                                                          NaN
    2               65  Player Props  ...                                                                                NaN                                                                          NaN
    3               60        Halves  ...                                                                                NaN                                                                          NaN
    4               61      Quarters  ...                                                                                NaN                                                                          NaN
    5               59    Game Props  ...                                                                                NaN                                                                          NaN
    6               69  Team Futures  ...                                                                                NaN                                                                          NaN
    7              576        Awards  ...                                                                     Gregg Popovich                                                                         True
    
    [8 rows x 16282 columns]
```

Sometimes transposing it makes it a little easier to slice
dft get you this

```
                                                                                                   0              1                 2         3            4                    5                    6               7
offerCategoryId                                                                                   62             66                65        60           61                   59                   69             576
name                                                                                      Game Lines   Series Lines      Player Props    Halves     Quarters           Game Props         Team Futures          Awards
offerSubcategoryDescriptors.0.subcategoryId                                                      262            979              2198       233          239                 4097                 1422            4896
offerSubcategoryDescriptors.0.name                                                              Game  Series Winner  First Field Goal  1st Half  1st Quarter  First Team to Score  Championship Winner             MVP
offerSubcategoryDescriptors.0.offerSubcategory.name                                             Game  Series Winner  First Field Goal  1st Half  1st Quarter  First Team to Score  Championship Winner             MVP
...                                                                                              ...            ...               ...       ...          ...                  ...                  ...             ...
offerSubcategoryDescriptors.4.offerSubcategory.offers.0.0.outcomes.30.oddsDecimal                NaN            NaN               NaN       NaN          NaN                  NaN                  NaN           251.0
offerSubcategoryDescriptors.4.offerSubcategory.offers.0.0.outcomes.30.oddsDecimalDisplay         NaN            NaN               NaN       NaN          NaN                  NaN                  NaN           251.0
offerSubcategoryDescriptors.4.offerSubcategory.offers.0.0.outcomes.30.oddsFractional             NaN            NaN               NaN       NaN          NaN                  NaN                  NaN           250/1
offerSubcategoryDescriptors.4.offerSubcategory.offers.0.0.outcomes.30.participant                NaN            NaN               NaN       NaN          NaN                  NaN                  NaN  Gregg Popovich
offerSubcategoryDescriptors.4.offerSubcategory.offers.0.0.outcomes.30.hidden                     NaN            NaN               NaN       NaN          NaN                  NaN                  NaN            True
```

Comment: Thank you! That does provide all of the data. How would you suggest I format the data so that all Game Lines go into their own dataframe and each Team populates on a separate row? They are currently all on the same row.

Comment: You'll need to find the right level of the overall dictionary to either json_normalize or flatten_json. You may have to process this via python into acceptable lists, then pass that into pandas. I just spent 10 minutes looking at it again and it's not clear what you want as I don't really understand the data itself. maybe draftkings has a schema, or try the library i posted in the my comments to the original question.